# The address structure that I want directions from my location information in google maps is no longer working

Tags: google-maps

A few months ago, I was able to get directions from my location to another location with a url as below, but I can no longer. I guess My + Location value doesn't work anymore. What do I need to enter this value as url to get my location information?

https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=my+location&daddr=40.7233772,29.9643515&z=14

Comment: Works fine for me. Told me to buy a $1500 plane ticket first. Chrome v78.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official Maps URLs:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=40.7233772,29.9643515

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action):

> `origin`: Defines the starting point from which to display directions. Defaults to most relevant starting location, such as user location, if available.